# Form no longer scrolls because of javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that follows the user as it scrolls down the page, but when I added the below JS it no longer scrolls and I'm not sure why. There is no change to the HTML or CSS aside from the below javascript, so I'm assuming something below is causing the issue. I've snipped out some countries and states to make this shorter and postable.

```
var country_arr = new Array("United States", "Uzbekistan");

// States
var s_a = new Array();
s_a[0] = "";

s_a[239] = "Alabama|Alaska|American Samoa|Arizona|Arkansas|Armed Forces America|Armed Forces Europe|Armed Forces Pacific|California|Colorado|Connecticut|Delaware|District of Columbia|Florida|Georgia|Guam|Hawaii|Idaho|Illinois|Indiana|Iowa|Kansas|Kentucky|Louisiana|Maine|Maryland|Massachusetts|Michigan|Minnesota|Mississippi|Missouri|Montana|Nebraska|Nevada|New Hampshire|New Jersey|New Mexico|New York|North Carolina|North Dakota|Northern Mariana Islands|Ohio|Oklahoma|Oregon|Pennsylvania|Rhode Island|South Carolina|South Dakota|Tennessee|Texas|Utah|Vermont|Virginia|Virgin Islands|Washington|West Virginia|Wisconsin|Wyoming";

function populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId) {

  var selectedCountryIndex = document.getElementById(countryElementId).selectedIndex;

  var stateElement = document.getElementById(stateElementId);

  stateElement.length = 0;
  stateElement.options[0] = new Option('Select State If Applicable', '');
  stateElement.selectedIndex = 0;

  var state_arr = s_a[selectedCountryIndex].split("|");

  for (var i = 0; i < state_arr.length; i++) {
    stateElement.options[stateElement.length] = new Option(state_arr[i], state_arr[i]);
  }
}

function populateCountries(countryElementId, stateElementId) {
  // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
  var countryElement = document.getElementById(countryElementId);
  countryElement.length = 0;
  countryElement.options[0] = new Option('Select Country', '-1');
  countryElement.selectedIndex = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
    countryElement.options[countryElement.length] = new Option(country_arr[i], country_arr[i]);
  }

  // Assigned all countries. Now assign event listener for the states.

  if (stateElementId) {
    countryElement.onchange = function() {
      populateStates(countryElementId, stateElementId);
    };
  }
}

function initCountryState() {
  //hide country and state fields first
  var countryEle = document.getElementById('country');
  var stateEle = document.getElementById('state');
  countryEle.style.display = 'none';
  stateEle.style.display = 'none';


  //Create and append select list for country and state
  var countrySelect = document.createElement("select");
  countrySelect.id = "country_select";
  countrySelect.addEventListener(
    'change',
    function() {
      countryEle.value = this.value;
    },
    false
  );
  countryEle.parentElement.insertBefore(countrySelect, countryEle);

  var stateSelect = document.createElement("select");
  stateSelect.id = "state_select";
  stateSelect.addEventListener(
    'change',
    function() {
      stateEle.value = this.value;
    },
    false
  );
  stateEle.parentElement.insertBefore(stateSelect, stateEle);
  populateCountries('country_select', 'state_select');
}
(function() {
  initCountryState();
})();
```

Comment: So are there errors in your console?

Comment: Can you update the code snippet to be a runnable demonstration of the problem?

Comment: The only error I see on console is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined
    at createDropdowns (site.js:31)
    at site.js:112
createDropdowns @ site.js:31
(anonymous) @ site.js:112

Comment: Well the code provided has no innerText